# Apply custom CSS to a React reusable component

Tags: reactjs

How can I apply a custom CSS to a react component that it's used in other two components? For example, I have a Container component which it is used in other two components, and the issue it's that I need to apply a custom css (width 90% and float prop for an image from the `Container` component) in one of those, **not for both**. So the width of 90% must be applied **only for one of the components** in which the `Container` it is used.
The `Container` component uses scss.

Comment: Do you heard something about the library [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)?

Comment: It's used in the component in which I have to modify the width, but how can I apply a custom width to an imported component with styled components?

Comment: So I figure it out, basically I need to expose className prop on the element on which I want to extend the css in my other react component. Case closed.